# compare Java Double.Max_VALUE with large double numbers returns true

Tags: java, double, ieee-754

Why do these simple double comparisons return true?

```
System.out.println(Double.MAX_VALUE == (Double.MAX_VALUE - 99 * Math.pow(10, 290)));
System.out.println(new Double(Double.MAX_VALUE).equals(new Double(Double.MAX_VALUE - 99 * Math.pow(10, 290))));
```

I know it's probably a `IEEE 754` precision problem, but I can't figure out what the exact problem is here.

Comment: That's not really "almost any number" - that's a few numbers logarithmically really close to `Double.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: From 0 to 99 * Math.pow(10, 290) actually...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Very large floating point numbers are **very** imprecise. What you are seeing is rounding error.

We could demonstrate floating point in base-10 (scientific notation), say with 1 digit for the exponent and 4 digits for the base:

```
1234*10^1  == 1234
1234*10^-1 == 123.4
1234*10^9  == 1,234,000,000,000
1235*10^9  == 1,235,000,000,000
```

It follows that:

```
1234*10^9 - 1234*10^1 == 1234*10^9
```

You can see that as the numbers get larger, we lose precision. Lots of it.

For kicks, you can test it:

```
double d = 10;
while(Double.MAX_VALUE - d == Double.MAX_VALUE)
    d *= 10;
System.out.println(d);
```

We can determine that the gap between `Double.MAX_VALUE` and the next smallest value (called an [ULP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place)) is somewhere around `10^292`, which is a very large gap.

We can determine its exact value with the help of [`Math#ulp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp-double-):

```
long       lng = Double.doubleToRawLongBits(Double.MAX_VALUE);
double nextMax = Double.longBitsToDouble(lng - 1);
System.out.println(Math.ulp(nextMax));
```

Which is about `1.99584*10^292`, or `2^971`.

Answer (score 3):

The larger floating-point numbers get, the larger the gap between one floating-point number and the next one down or up. This is because an error of 0.5 is pretty important in a measurement of value 1, but utterly insignificant in a measurement of value 1000000000000.

`Double.MAX_VALUE` is huge, and the numbers you're subtracting from it are less huge. In fact, the difference is big enough that the numbers you're subtracting are less huge than the gap between `Double.MAX_VALUE` and the next double down, so `Double.MAX_VALUE` is the closest representable number to the exact result. Thus, you just get `Double.MAX_VALUE` back.

Comment: Specifically, the gap between Double.MAX_VALUE and the largest double that is less than it is about 1.9958403095347198E292, a very big gap indeed. You would need to subtract at least half of that difference to affect the value.

Answer (score -3):

I think the problem is in this line

```
                                                        |  
                                                        v
new Double(Double.MAX_VALUE).equals(new Double(Double.MAX_VALUE - 99999999999999999999999D))
```

DOUBLE MAX_VALUE = Double.MAX_VALUE - 99999999999999999999999D

AND you're comparing it with

new Double(Double.MAX_VALUE - 99999999999999999999999D)

which I think is just the same so it will always return true.

Comment: No, that isn't a problem at all.  You're going from a primitive to a wrapper, which doesn't lose data at all.